# AWS API Gateway: How to achieve continuous delivery?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I'm building an API using AWS API Gateway and AWS Lambda. I would like to achieve continuous delivery for this API. The path I've chosen to do it is to use CloudFormation through AWS CodePipeline. I've managed to to it for another project using Lambdas (without API Gateway), it works perfectly and it is really pleasant to use.

The issue I'm facing when deploying is that the Lambdas are properly updated but not the API definition. From what I understand, the AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment are immutable resources which means that for each deployment of the API I need to create a new AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment resource. This is not practical at all because for each of this AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment I have a new Invoke URL. This is not acceptable since I would have to either change my DNS record to the newly deployed API invoke URL or ask our API users to change the URL in their applications.

What I would like is to be able to change the API definition and the Lambdas implementations without my API users having to change anything in their applications.

How can I achieve this behavior?

I created a tutorial to highlight my issue. You can find it at: https://github.com/JonathanGailliez/aws-api-gateway-lambda-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=789869&#789869

joey-aws says:

> We are currently in the process of rolling out a solution which
>   addresses this exact problem. In the meantime, a common workaround
>   would be to update something small, such as a "description" field
>   which could then be used to "trigger" an API Gateway deployment when
>   updating the CloudFormation stack.

I'll update this answer and the example repo once it's rolled out.

Answer (score 1):

You could run a Cloudformation update from the command line or in the AWS console.  This would change the API definitions and any lambda code without changing the unique id to access your gateway.

The other option is to put your API behind a custom domain name and then you could keep deploy a new API or stage and switch over the custom domain mapping when you are ready.  The users wouldn't recognize any change.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your suggestions. AWS is working on a solution for this particular issue. I'll wait for them to roll out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

A way to achieve that is by leveraging existing frameworks like

1. [AWS SAM](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model)
2. [Serverless](https://github.com/serverless/serverless)
3. [Claudia](https://github.com/claudiajs/claudia)

Comment: Hi Shimon, thanks you for these recommendations. I'll have a look to see how these can improve what I've done so far. In the mean times, AWS is working on a solution to the issue highlighted in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by using CloudFormation template generated by troposphere and boto3 api in Python as follows:

1. Split the template into two parts

   - API definition, Method(s), IAM roles, ApiKey and Lambda (a)
   - Deployment, UsagePlan and UsagePlanKey (b)
2. Once changed Lambda code is zipped up and uploaded to S3 using boto3 api
3. Stack (b) is deleted
4. Stack (a) is updated with new resource id for the GET method connected to lambda
5. Stack (b) is created anew

Steps 3, 4, 5 are performed using CloudFormation boto3 api with blocking until completed.

Most importantly after all steps are done ApiKey value and stage Invoke URL *remain the same, running updated Lambda code* as tested with curl.

Note: it may take additional 30-60s for API to become fully functional after CloudFormation update is completed.